# How to target a button from a group of buttons in JQuery without a class name or id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

How can I target a button from a group of buttons without using a class or id, just n JQuery

Example:

```html
<body>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button class="food">Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <input type="text">
  <!--
     <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/…>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
  -->
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the button/group?

Comment: I agree with @ITgoldman; more context would be useful. Its parent element(s), value, and more can be used to target it.

Comment: DOM navigation.

Comment: @ITgoldman                                                                                                      <body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <button class="food">Click Me</button>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <input type="text">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: you can target the 5th button using a selector like button:nth-child(5)

Comment: @ITgoldman  button:nth-child(5)  this solved the problem but it targeted the third button, anyway, thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery this would only be possible if the button's had unique innerText or innerHTML that you could then predict.

Using my example HTML from below:

```html
<div>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
  <button>Button3</button>
  <button>Button4</button>
</div>
```

You would need to use JQuery to grab all  tags, and then filter that by their innerHTML or innerText depending on what is inside the button tag.

See the below JS:

```js
// Assuming you want 'Button 1'
for(let el of $("button")){
  if(el.innerText === 'Button1') el.addEventListener() // Then from here do the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There many ways, You can use onclick method inline Html. A crude way---

```
<script>

function function1(){

alert ('Button1')
}

function function2(){

alert ('Button2')
}
function function3 (){

alert ('Button3')
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="function1()">Button 1</button>

<button onclick="function2()">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="function3()">Button 3</button>
</body>
```